# Tensorflow ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a face detection model with CNN. I used codes that I made for number detection. When I use number images, program work. But, when I use my face images, I get an error that is:

Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Notebook link: https://github.com/AkifCanSonmez/ImageProccessingCourse/blob/main/CNN/Number%20Classification%20Project/Building%20Model/Building%20Number%20Classification%20Model%20with%20Keras.ipynb

Number image:[image: a number image]

Face image:[image: a face image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input images have a shape of `(32,32,3)` whil you first conv2D layer sets the inputshape to `(32,32,1)`. Most likely your numbers have only 1 channel since they are grayscale, while you face images have 3 color channels.

change:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape = (32,32,1), filters = 8, kernel_size = (5,5),activation = "relu", padding = "same" ))
```

to

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape = (32,32,3), filters = 8, kernel_size = (5,5),activation = "relu", padding = "same" ))
```

Comment: This solved my issue. In my case it was also that some one-hot-encoded labels were just zeros, so double check your data!

Comment: I have the same error but this is my line of code: 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(32,32,3)))

Would you be able to guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that you declared initialised all the parameters in the compile functions , i had the exact error when i forgot to initialise batch_size in the fit function after the compile function.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the solution of the problem was a bad definition of the function **len**() of my custom data generator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).