# Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)

Tags: tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, imagedatagenerator

when i run model.fit i get the following error : Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from patchify import patchify
from PIL import Image
np.random.seed(42) 

seed =42


batch_size= 8
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_data_gen_args = dict(rescale = 1/255.0)

mask_data_gen_args = dict(rescale = 1/255.0) #Binarize the output again.#Binarize the output again. 

image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(**img_data_gen_args)
image_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/train_images/", 
                                                           seed=42, 
                                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           target_size=(224,224),
                                                           class_mode=None)  #Very important to set this otherwise it returns multiple numpy arrays 
                                                                            #thinking class mode is binary.

mask_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(**mask_data_gen_args)
mask_generator = mask_data_generator.flow_from_directory("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/train_masks/", 
                                                         seed=42, 
                                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                                         target_size=(224,224),
                                                         color_mode = 'grayscale',   #Read masks in grayscale
                                                         class_mode=None)


valid_img_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/val_images/", 
                                                               seed=42, 
                                                               batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                               target_size=(224,224),
                                                               class_mode=None) #Default batch size 32, if not specified here
valid_mask_generator = mask_data_generator.flow_from_directory("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/val_masks/", 
                                                               seed=42, 
                                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                                               target_size=(224,224),
                                                               color_mode = 'grayscale',   #Read masks in grayscale
                                                               class_mode=None)  #Default batch size 32, if not specified here


train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
val_generator = zip(valid_img_generator, valid_mask_generator)

x = image_generator.next()
y = mask_generator.next()
for i in range(0,1):
    image = x[i]
    mask = y[i]
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
print(image.shape)
print(mask.shape)

    
"""-------------metrics-----------------"""   
#Jaccard distance loss mimics IoU. 
from keras import backend as K
def jaccard_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred, smooth=100):
   
    intersection = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1))
    sum_ = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1))
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return (1 - jac) * smooth

#Dice metric can be a great metric to track accuracy of semantic segmentation.
def dice_metric(y_pred, y_true):
    intersection = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1))
    union = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1))
    # if y_pred.sum() == 0 and y_pred.sum() == 0:
    #     return 1.0

    return 2*intersection / union

"""-----------------------------------------"""
IMG_HEIGHT = x.shape[1]
IMG_WIDTH  = x.shape[2]
IMG_CHANNELS = x.shape[3]

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, MaxPool2D, Concatenate

"""----------------Model-------------------"""

def conv_block(input, num_filters):
    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)   #Not in the original network. 
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)  #Not in the original network
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x

#Encoder block: Conv block followed by maxpooling


def encoder_block(input, num_filters):
    x = conv_block(input, num_filters)
    p = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
    return x, p   

#Decoder block
#skip features gets input from encoder for concatenation

def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(input)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip_features])
    x = conv_block(x, num_filters)
    return x

#Build Unet using the blocks
def build_unet(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    s1, p1 = encoder_block(inputs, 64)
    s2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, 128)
    s3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, 256)
    s4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, 512)

    b1 = conv_block(p4, 1024) #Bridge

    d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 64)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(d4)  #Binary (can be multiclass)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="U-Net")
    return model

"""----------------------------------------------"""

input_shape = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS)

model = build_unet(input_shape)
from focal_loss import BinaryFocalLoss

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 1e-3), loss=BinaryFocalLoss(gamma=2),
              metrics=[dice_metric])


model.summary()
```

works fine till here.
Output is:

```
Found 130 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 130 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 33 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 33 images belonging to 1 classes.
(224, 224, 3)
(224, 224, 1)
Model: "U-Net"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_11 (InputLayer)          [(None, 224, 224, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_190 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64  1792        ['input_11[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_180 (Batch  (None, 224, 224, 64  256        ['conv2d_190[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_180 (Activation)    (None, 224, 224, 64  0           ['batch_normalization_180[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_191 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64  36928       ['activation_180[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_181 (Batch  (None, 224, 224, 64  256        ['conv2d_191[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_181 (Activation)    (None, 224, 224, 64  0           ['batch_normalization_181[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 112, 112, 64  0          ['activation_181[0][0]']         
 )                              )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_192 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 12  73856       ['max_pooling2d_40[0][0]']       
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_182 (Batch  (None, 112, 112, 12  512        ['conv2d_192[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_182 (Activation)    (None, 112, 112, 12  0           ['batch_normalization_182[0][0]']
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_193 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 12  147584      ['activation_182[0][0]']         
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_183 (Batch  (None, 112, 112, 12  512        ['conv2d_193[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_183 (Activation)    (None, 112, 112, 12  0           ['batch_normalization_183[0][0]']
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 56, 56, 128)  0          ['activation_183[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_194 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)  295168      ['max_pooling2d_41[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_184 (Batch  (None, 56, 56, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_194[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_184 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 256)  0           ['batch_normalization_184[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_195 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)  590080      ['activation_184[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_185 (Batch  (None, 56, 56, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_195[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_185 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 256)  0           ['batch_normalization_185[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 28, 28, 256)  0          ['activation_185[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_196 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 512)  1180160     ['max_pooling2d_42[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_186 (Batch  (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048       ['conv2d_196[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_186 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           ['batch_normalization_186[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_197 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 512)  2359808     ['activation_186[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_187 (Batch  (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048       ['conv2d_197[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_187 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           ['batch_normalization_187[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_43 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 14, 14, 512)  0          ['activation_187[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_198 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 1024  4719616     ['max_pooling2d_43[0][0]']       
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_188 (Batch  (None, 14, 14, 1024  4096       ['conv2d_198[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_188 (Activation)    (None, 14, 14, 1024  0           ['batch_normalization_188[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_199 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 1024  9438208     ['activation_188[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_189 (Batch  (None, 14, 14, 1024  4096       ['conv2d_199[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_189 (Activation)    (None, 14, 14, 1024  0           ['batch_normalization_189[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_40 (Conv2DTra  (None, 28, 28, 512)  2097664    ['activation_189[0][0]']         
 nspose)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_40 (Concatenate)   (None, 28, 28, 1024  0           ['conv2d_transpose_40[0][0]',    
                                )                                 'activation_187[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_200 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 512)  4719104     ['concatenate_40[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_190 (Batch  (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048       ['conv2d_200[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_190 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           ['batch_normalization_190[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_201 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 512)  2359808     ['activation_190[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_191 (Batch  (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048       ['conv2d_201[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_191 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           ['batch_normalization_191[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_41 (Conv2DTra  (None, 56, 56, 256)  524544     ['activation_191[0][0]']         
 nspose)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_41 (Concatenate)   (None, 56, 56, 512)  0           ['conv2d_transpose_41[0][0]',    
                                                                  'activation_185[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_202 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)  1179904     ['concatenate_41[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_192 (Batch  (None, 56, 56, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_202[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_192 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 256)  0           ['batch_normalization_192[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_203 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)  590080      ['activation_192[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_193 (Batch  (None, 56, 56, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_203[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_193 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 256)  0           ['batch_normalization_193[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_42 (Conv2DTra  (None, 112, 112, 12  131200     ['activation_193[0][0]']         
 nspose)                        8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_42 (Concatenate)   (None, 112, 112, 25  0           ['conv2d_transpose_42[0][0]',    
                                6)                                'activation_183[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_204 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 12  295040      ['concatenate_42[0][0]']         
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_194 (Batch  (None, 112, 112, 12  512        ['conv2d_204[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_194 (Activation)    (None, 112, 112, 12  0           ['batch_normalization_194[0][0]']
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_205 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 12  147584      ['activation_194[0][0]']         
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_195 (Batch  (None, 112, 112, 12  512        ['conv2d_205[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_195 (Activation)    (None, 112, 112, 12  0           ['batch_normalization_195[0][0]']
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_43 (Conv2DTra  (None, 224, 224, 64  32832      ['activation_195[0][0]']         
 nspose)                        )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_43 (Concatenate)   (None, 224, 224, 12  0           ['conv2d_transpose_43[0][0]',    
                                8)                                'activation_181[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_206 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64  73792       ['concatenate_43[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_196 (Batch  (None, 224, 224, 64  256        ['conv2d_206[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_196 (Activation)    (None, 224, 224, 64  0           ['batch_normalization_196[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_207 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64  36928       ['activation_196[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_197 (Batch  (None, 224, 224, 64  256        ['conv2d_207[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_197 (Activation)    (None, 224, 224, 64  0           ['batch_normalization_197[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_208 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 1)  65          ['activation_197[0][0]']
```

```
num_train_imgs = len(os.listdir("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/train_images/"))
steps_per_epoch = num_train_imgs //batch_size
num_val_images = len(os.listdir("E:/FAGR_small/patches/data_for_training_and_testing/val_images/"))
validation_steps = num_val_images //batch_size

history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, 
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                    validation_steps=validation_steps, epochs=50)
```

After running model.fit I get:

```
Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

Comment: This error is caused when you define the model with a different image color channel than the images are in actuality. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832127/14290681) similar issue for your reference.